# (React Native) ¿Cómo puedo cambiar un useState de la parte del Navigator en otra screen mediante un botón?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Actualmente estoy creando una app en React Native (soy nuevo) y he creado un modo oscuro desde la parte del Navigator que se cambia con un useSate.

El problema es que quiero cambiar ese useState desde otra pantalla y no sé cómo hacerlo, por ejemplo desde otra pantalla mediante un botón, espero alguien pueda ayudarme

No sé si es algo difícil de hacer o soy yo el que se está complicando con el código!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya intentaste pasarle `setDarkMode` como props a la página que necesitas?

Comment: No, cómo puedo hacerlo??